# How to add ListBox Item Contextmenu in UWP

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am searching to add Context menu in every item of my listbox item. I know it was very easy in wp8 app using toolkit. However, Toolkit is not supported in uwp.

How can I add Context menu in uwp listbox item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create [ListBox.ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate) with [MenuFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.aspx), for example:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" >
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton"
                                                            Text="Edit"
                                                            Click="EditButton_Click"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                                            Text="Delete"
                                                            Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Handle the PointerEntered event to show Flyout when the pointer has been moved into an ListBoxItem:

```
private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
            FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);
            flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
}
```

Handle MenuFlyoutItem Click event:

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            var datacontext = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

            //this datacontext is probably some object of some type T
}

private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            var datacontext = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

            //this datacontext is probably some object of some type T
}
```

**Please check my feasible sample on [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/ListBoxContextMenuUWPApp1)**

Comment: Thanks, I think this may solve my problem. However, as you mentioned flyout menu appear when mouse pointer enters the control. I want it appear as context menu appears in wp8. Is it possible?

Comment: @ARH If you need to show Flyout menu using right-click/Tap, handle RightTapped event, please check my latest commit code in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I think RightTapped only works with mobile phones. It doesn't work with desktop version.

Comment: @ARH I've tested on Windows10, it worked well by right-clicking

Comment: Thanks for this. Instead of using the PointerEntered event, though, I used the RightTapped event (which works with right-click of mouse or long-tap on the touchscreen of my Surface), and got the desire I wanted. I appreciate your answer, as it got me most of the way to what I needed.